# Clearing sessions in mongodb, expressjs, nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, everyauth

My configuration:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'MY SECRET',
        store: new MongoStore({
            db: 'MY SESSION DB',
            host: 'localhost',
            port:88888
        })
    }));
    app.use(everyauth.middleware());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

    app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('dev', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
    appPort = config.port; //Setting PORT to 8888 in dev mode.
    app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
    appPort = config.port;
    //Set cache-header-expires to 1 day
    var oneDay = 86400000;
    //app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneDay }));
});
```

Now, I have a 'logout' link which goes to /logout on my app.

AFAIK, express automatically takes care of clearing sessions on logout. But with my config, I dont think its doing that. For example, A custom variable attached to session

```
req.session.custom
```

still holds after logout. However,

```
req.session.auth
```

is cleared after logout.

The number of session object in my MongoDb store are only incrementing over time. I am using ***everyauth*** as well.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to fully clear the session for the user on logout you can call `req.session.destroy()` from your `everyauth.everymodule.handleLogout` function.  Only `req.session.auth` is cleared when you call `req.logout()`.

Comment: How can I go about deleting the object in my Mongo session store as well on logout?

Comment: `req.session.destroy()` deletes the session object from your store.

Comment: I dont think req.session.destroy() is clearing it. Both before and after logout, count() on the store is 1 when I test. Any clue?

Comment: Does your logout redirect to a login page?  That would then create a new session to replace the one you just destroyed during logout and make it look like nothing changed.

Comment: You are right. Its creating a new one. I check the session id. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: why is it creating a new session in mongo store.Is there any way to prevent it when i am redirected to login again.

Answer (score 3):

> why is it creating a new session in mongo store.Is there any way to
> prevent it when i am redirected to login again. – loneranger Jun 7 '15 at 5:43

There's a [**saveUninitialized**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#saveuninitialized) option to prevent the session to be saved if it does not contain any data.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret123',
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
        ttl: 60 * 30 // half hour
    }),
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```